# Is it possible to convert a machine image to raw and pipe to `dd` at same time?

Tags: linux, pipe, qemu, dd

First off, some background:

I was tasked with creating a way to boot, configure, and save a virtual machine in a format that can be used on a physical hard drive. I accomplished this with Vagrant, Packer, and VirtualBox.

The problem is that in order to use it on a real hard drive, the output `.vmdk` needs to be converted to a raw format and written to the hard drive with the `dd` utility. The raw format is quite large because there's no shortening of empty space in this format; it's exactly as large as the file system is when it gets generated.

Is it possible to convert the `.vmdk` image to raw and pipe it to `dd` without expanding it on the writer's file system?

I've tried looking around for any existing solutions, but haven't come up with much. My guess is it's not possible.

Comment: guessing `qemu-img convert file.vmdk - > /dev/disc0p1` ? `qemu-img convert file.vmdk /dev/stdout`? Or really just `qemu-img convert file.vmdk /dev/disc0p1`?

Comment: Hey thanks! I can give that a try. Can you elaborate on the use of `/dev/disc0p1`? I'm not familiar.

Comment: It's the real device hard drive you are copying to. /dev/sda0 or similar.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, I thought for a moment it might be an intermediate device or something `dd` uses I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else that might come across this, the solution was (as usual) to [RTFM](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/tools/qemu-img.html#cmdoption-qemu-img-arg-dd)

The `qemu-img` utility has this functionality built into it, with a `dd` option.

The command is pretty much the syntax of `dd` tacked onto the end of the `qemu-img` utility parameters.

E.g. `qemu-img dd -f vmdk -O raw if=your-image.vmdk of=/dev/sda bs=16M status=progress`